# $\mathcal{A}:= \{\bigcap \mathcal{E}\mid \mathcal{E} \subseteq \mathcal{B}, |\mathcal{E}| \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a basis

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Prove the following statement:

> Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{B} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then
>    $\mathcal{A}:= \{\bigcap \mathcal{E}\mid \mathcal{E} \subseteq
>  \mathcal{B}, |\mathcal{E}| \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a basis for a unique
>   topology on $X$.

I have already proved that the following two statements are equivalent:

> (1) $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is a basis for a unique
>   topology on $X$
>
> (2) $\forall A,B \in \mathcal{A}: \forall x \in A \cap B:\exists C \in
>  \mathcal{A}: x \in C \subseteq A \cap B$ and $\mathcal{A}$ is a cover
>   of $X$

So I'll use this in my attempt.

Take $\mathcal{E} := \emptyset$, the empty family. Then $X =\bigcap\mathcal{E} \in \mathcal{A}$. Hence, $X \subseteq \bigcup\mathcal{A} \subseteq X$ and it follows that $\mathcal{A}$ covers $X$.

Now, if $A := \bigcap \mathcal{E_1}, B := \bigcap \mathcal{E_2} \in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mathcal{E_i}\subseteq \mathcal{B} \quad(i=1,2)$, then

$$A\cap B = \bigcap \mathcal{E_1} \cup  \mathcal{E_2}$$ and $\mathcal{E_1} \cup  \mathcal{E_2} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, a finite union, so that for every $x \in A\cap B$, we can simply take $C:= A \cap B$ and this completes the proof.

Is this correct?

Comment: Looks correct to me.

Comment: Yes, it is correct. In order to avoid confusion I would add some brackets and write $\bigcap(\mathcal E_1\cup\mathcal E_2)$.

Comment: Thanks both for the verification.